# Embeddable databases and toplink

Tags: sqlite, toplink

I'm trying to get toplink and jsqlite to work. But I get a similar error like this thread: [JPA+SQLite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906241/jpasqlite-problem)

```
Exception Description: SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE: platform DatabasePlatform doesn't support NativeSequence.
```

I'm not sure it jsqlite even works with toplink, since I couldn't find a description somewhere.. I just need an embeddable database, so alternative suggestions are available, as long as they are easy to set up.

Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider</provider>
    <class>..</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:blah.db"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
      <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

From

> Exception Description:
>   SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE: platform
>   DatabasePlatform doesn't support
>   NativeSequence

Did you try to use table sequencing instead?

For more information see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Relational_Projects_%28ELUG%29#Table_Sequencing
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_(ELUG)#Configuring_Sequence_Generation